# Get Rows based on column value from csv

Tags: awk

I have a csv with the below data

```
10.000.00.00,D3,1
10.001.00.00,C4,2
10.002.00.00,C5,2
10.000.88.99,B1,3
10.000.00.00,B2,3
10.000.00.00,C6,3
10.000.99.00,D1,3
```

tried below code

```
cat Data.csv | awk -F , '$3 == "3" { print }'
```

Need to get only the rows having last values as 3.

Please let me know how to do this

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Your code does exactly what it's supposed to do. Maybe a little awkward.

Comment: Assuming your posted code doesn't do what you expected - your input file has DOS line-endings. Use `cat -v Data.csv` to see them and then `dos2unix` or similar to remove them. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45772568/1745001 for details.

Comment: @Sandy: To avoid the described problem, you can append the following to your mawk or gawk command to handle DOS and Unix line-endings: `-v RS='\n|\r\n'`

Comment: @Cyrus `'\n|\r\n'` = `\r?\n`. That approach will fail of course if there truly are supposed to be DOS line endings such as from an Excel export to a CSV where lines end in `\r\n` but can contain `\n`s inside quoted fields.

Comment: @EdMorton: That's correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using awk *to get only the rows having last values as 3*:

```
$ awk -F, '$NF==3' file
10.000.88.99,B1,3
10.000.00.00,B2,3
10.000.00.00,C6,3
10.000.99.00,D1,3
```

Explained:

```
awk -F, '  # set the field separator to a comma
$NF==3     # NF is the last field, $NF last field value (see comments for more
' file                                                  #thanks @kvantour)
```

Comment: The reason this works is because **(a)** a numeric comparison is enforced as fields are both numeric and string at the same time **(b)** `$NF` is converted to a numeric value using [`strod`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html) and the latter ignores unrecognized characters (such as `\r`)

Answer (score 2):

You can try with sed :

```
sed '/,3$/!d' infile
```

If you can have \r at end of lines, try this way :

```
sed '/,3\r*$/!d' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

> *Why do we need `awk` or `sed` for this kind of operations in the first place??? Isn't it an overkill?*
>
> OP is asking about **extracting some lines meeting a specific
>   condition** from the file without even modifying their format...

`grep` is ***THE*** perfect tool for this.

```
$ grep ',3$' Data.csv 
10.000.88.99,B1,3
10.000.00.00,B2,3
10.000.00.00,C6,3
10.000.99.00,D1,3
```

Eventually `grep -E ',3\r?$' Data.csv` if you have windows EOLs.

Also try avoiding as much as possible `cat <FILE> | <COMMAND>`, instead pass directly the file to the command or redirect the `stdin` from the file to the command (`Command < file`).

Answer (score 0):

you can use built in awk variable for this.

in our case

> **'$NF' - NF is for the number of fields in the current record**

```
awk -F, '{if($NF == 3) {print $0} }' Data.csv
10.000.88.99,B1,3
10.000.00.00,B2,3
10.000.00.00,C6,3
10.000.99.00,D1,3
```

You can learn more about built in varible at following link:
[Awk Built in Variables](https://www.linuxnix.com/awk-scripting-learn-awk-built-in-variables-with-examples/)